# Mirror sub-directories in output folder using bat and imagemagick

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

My BAT file currently scans all sub-directories of "JPG" and executes imagemagick on all files found within them before sending them to "output":

```
for /r /d %%a in (JPG\*) do magick convert "%%~a\*.jpg" resize 500000@ -set filename:out %%t_%%wx%%h "output/%%[filename:out].jpg"
```

I'd like to be able to mirror the folder structure of "JPG" in "output" e.g.

```
JPG/dir1/*.jpg
JPF/dir2/*.jpg

output/dir1/*.jpg
output/dir2/*.jpg
```

I am unsure as to how to go about this and was hoping I could get some guidance.

Comment: FYI. In IM 7 use only magick and not magick convert. In IM 6, use convert. For all other IM 7 tools use magick tool, such as magick identify or magick mogrify or magick montage, etc. Sorry I do not use Windows, so cannot help in your bat file.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you! I have made the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /L /S /Y "JPG\*" "output\" ^|findstr /v /e /L /i /c:" file(s)" ') do magick convert "%%~a" resize 500000@ -set filename:out %%t_%%wx%%h "output\%%~na.jpg"
```

This generates a list (`/L`) of the files that *would* be copied from `jpg` and its subdirectories (`/S`) - the `/Y` skips the default prompt. This list (of source files) is then assigned to `%%a` by the `for/f` - the `delims` clause ensuring that the entire name is assigned, regardless of separators by defining the delimiters to be used as *nothing*.

Please note that I'm unfamiliar with the intricacies of `magick`'s commands - `%%a` should provide the full filename; `%%~na` the name part only (ie. without the path and without the extension)

Also, paths in Windows are indicated by a backslash, not `/`. The conversion is not reliable since `/` is used to indicate a switch.

[edit: added `findstr` command to eliminate output lines that `/e` end in the `/L` literal "<kbd>Space</kbd>file(s)" with `/i` case-insensitivity]

---

Further thoughts:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "destdir2=destdir"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /L /S /Y "JPG\*" "output\" ^|findstr /v /e /L /i /c:" file(s)" ') DO (
 ECHO magick convert "%%~a" resize 500000@ -set filename:out %%t_%%wx%%h "output\%%~na.jpg"
 SET "outdir=%%~a"
 SET "outdir=!outdir:\%%~nxa=!"
 SET "outdir=%destdir%!outdir:~3!"
 ECHO MD "!outdir!" 2>nul
 ECHO magick convert "%%~a" resize 500000@ -set filename:out %%t_%%wx%%h "!outdir!\%%~na.jpg"
 SET "outdir=%%~a"
 SET "outdir=!outdir:\%%~nxa=!"
 SET "outdir=%destdir2%!outdir:~3!"
 ECHO MD "!outdir!" 2>nul
 ECHO magick convert "%%~a" resize 500000@ -set filename:out %%t_%%wx%%h "!outdir!\%%~na.jpg"
 ECHO ==================
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I usually completely specify the source and destination directories.

The above code should take the files in the source directory and produce three separate output sets for each file found according to the filemask selected. The proposed commands are simply `echo`ed to allow appropriate selection of desired result.

The first set uses the original code - no surprises there.

The second and third sets establish a variable named `outdir` which contains the source filename. Since substringing of metavariables is not allowed, the value is transferred to an ordinary environment variable and `delayedexpansion` invoked to allow *that* value to be manipulated within the code-block.

First, the final backslash, name and extension are removed, leaving the path. Then the first 3 characters are removed (the `JPG`) and appended to the output directoryname in either `destdir` or `destdir2` and the directory is created. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages like when the destination directory already exists.

And then we execute `magick`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am getting the following error: "unable to open image 'resize'. Looks like something may be missing.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what `magick`'s commands are. It would appear that it is interpreting `resize` as a filename. If you use `echo magick...` instead of `magick` then the actual command will be displayed. You will probably be able to make the fix from there. BTW - you don't show how your original code sets `%%t`,`%%w` and `%%h` - without a representative code sample, we're guessing.

Comment: So the issue with resize was a simple typo on my end; sorry about that. Here's what I have so far: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /L /S /Y "JPG\*" "output\" ') do magick "%%~a" -resize 500000@ -set filename:out %%t_%%wx%%h "output\%%[filename:out].jpg"` This converts all the images in JPG, but fails to create matching folders in output. Moreover, after converting the images in JPG, I get an error about magick not being able to "open image '2 file(s)', which is the number of files in JPG

Comment: BTW, `%%t,%%w` and `%%h` are magick commands that append width and height to the filename.

Comment: Just saw your edit, thank you. This fixes the issue with the error about magick not being able to "open image '2 file(s)'. It still does not create matching subfolders in "output" and instead puts all the files in the root of "output".